# Catalina Beta 5: Quicktime Audio Recording Not Working on 2018 Macbook Pros

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, quicktime, microphone, catalina

Starting a Quicktime Audio recording with Catalina Dev Beta 5 on 2018 or later Macbook Pros outputs files with no sound (Macbook Pro Microhone selected). Example file here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ib67k0vg8cm93fn/test_no_audio%20%281%29.aifc?dl=0

During the recording recording Console shows this error:

"CMIO_Unit_Converter_Audio.cpp:590:RebuildAudioConverter AudioConverterSetProperty() failed (1886547824)"

We have an application that records the screen and audio at the same time using AVFoundation and the resulting video files also do not have audio. However when inspecting the CMSampleBuffers, they seem fine: https://gist.github.com/paulius005/faef6d6250323b7d3386a9a70c08f70b

Is anyone else experiencing this issue or possibly have more visibility if it's something Apple is working on?

Anything else that I should be looking at to tackle the issue?

Comment: I just tried a test recording on Catabline dev beta 5 using Quicktime.  I don't have any problem with either recording or playback. I used my 2015 MBP mic.  Maybe it's something specific to your device or how you're doing it?

Comment: Hey @fsb I've tested this on 3 different 2018 MBPs with their internal mic and non of them work. It works fine if using an external mic though :(

Comment: That's really strange. I'm just opening QuickTime, making a short audio recording using the built-in mic, saving the file, then playing it. Works fine. I have a 2015 MBP so maybe it's that?

Comment: Yep yep, on older devices it works just fine

Comment: I have MacOS Catalina Beta 5 (19A526h) and QuickTime refuses to record audio. It's not a permission problem because QuickTIme very explicitly tells you if it does not have access to your mike. I only have an internal mike. No external audio devices whatsoever. I am also using a 2018 Macbook Pro.

Comment: @SpencerWilliams have you reported it to Apple?

Comment: I have not, as it is looking like this is particular to newer MacBooks and this particular version of Catalina. Basically, I'm just going to really take home the lesson here that I should avoid installing beta MacOS on a computer I rely on a lot. But yeah, we should report this with the Feedback Assistant or something.

Comment: @SpencerWilliams just checking in here that you reported the issue :) I think it's important that we do so Apple can fix this. For transparency I'm pushing here because my whole business is recording video with audio, so this would be quite impactful if it didn't work

Comment: Consider this issue reported by me.

Comment: Still an issue in beta 6

Comment: Even though theres a bounty on this I still vote to close this question in my mind, because we have no way of knowing whether this is related to the fact that its in beta and could be fixed by simply waiting for a new software update.

Answer (score 1):

There are new beta updates. Can you check them and see if the issue persists.